# Junit5 Spring Boot Autowire ComponentScan Not Working

Tags: java, spring, junit5, spring-boot-test

My problem: if my test refers to an `@Bean` declaration in the class listed in `@SpringBootTest`, autowire works.  If it refers to a class automatically `@ComponentScan`ned by the class listed in `@SpringBootTest`, autowire fails.  Outside of testing, my app starts without autowire or componentscan issues, and I can confirm that the service I want to load in my test runs fine from non-test.  I'm frustrated as hell.  Am I broken, or is Junit5 functionality on Spring Boot 2?

My Test:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest (classes=MyConfig.class)
public class MyTest {
    // fails to autowire
    @Autowired
    private MyService _mySvc ;

    // succeeds!
    @Autowired @Qualifier ( "wtf" )
    private String _wtf ;
```

MyConfig:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@SpringBootApplication ( scanBasePackages = "my.packaging" )
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {

    @Bean
    public String wtf ( ) { return "W T F???" ; }

    // No @Bean for MyService because component scan is nicer in the non-test world
```

Comment: @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyConfig .class) try this

Comment: SpringRunner is Junit4.

Comment: For that matter, so is @RunWith.  Removing it doesn't change anything, so I take it out of my sample.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had the same issue with autowiring not working although the test was starting and the problem was that I was still using the old junit4 @Test annotation.
Make sure your test method is annotated with @Test from juni5 package org.junit.jupiter.api.Test.

Answer (score 2):

I think because you have annotated as such:

```
@SpringBootTest (classes=MyConfig.class)
```

Spring will only look in `MyConfig.class` for the appropriate beans and is not able to find one for `MyService`, however, I presume that Spring will scan all packages for a bean when the application is running normally. This is why it works fine in non-test.

Comment: Interesting.  How do I get it to then scan the packages I need scanned, if MyConfig is already a Configuration with a scanner enabled?

Comment: Maybe try adding the `@ComponentScan` annotation to the test class. - I'm not very familiar with Spring testing annotations, usually set it up once for what I need each project and then forget how it works

Comment: @billmill If you only annotate your class with `@SpringBootTest` it will first check if there is a nested `@Configuration` class available and if not fallback to automatically look for classes annotated with `@SpringBootConfiguration` within the classpath, `@SpringBootApplication` is i.e. annotated with `@SpringBootConfiguration` and therfore should be found. If you provide classes via `@SpringBootTest` then these classes are taken instead of letting Spring determine the actual Spring boot application classes.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Tudro said, `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test` is for Junit 5. `org.junit.Test` is for Junit 4.

Use this below:

```java
@ExtendedWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
```

Comment: org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith, not ExtendedWith !

Comment: @ExtendedWith(SpringExtension.class) is already called in @SpringBootTest

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could add `@ContextConfiguration(classes = ApplicationConfiguration.class)`

It would look like this

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import example06.junit.group01.Piano;

@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ApplicationConfiguration.class)
public class ApplicationConfigurationTest {
    @Autowired
    private Piano piano;
    
    @Test
    public void shouldTestPiano() {
        System.err.println("Testing JUnit5 > " + piano);
    }
}
```

My config is a simple class

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class ApplicationConfiguration {

}
```